# Silent install FirePro v4900 Driver on Windows Embedded 7 Standard

Tags: drivers, silent-install, windows-embedded-7

I'm trying to install the Drivers for a FirePro v4900 on a Windows Embedded 7 Standard 64bit OS. I want the system to be as small as possible, so i would rather not install the whole catalyst control center, but only the necessary drivers. Because the installation should be accomplished absolutely unattended, the installation process of the FirePro-Driver should also be done without any user interaction. I see two possible solutions for the Problem:

1. Install only the Drivers: Is it possible to solely install the necessary drivers? How would i achieve that? This solution would be the preferred one, because of the smaller footprint.
2. Silent custom install the provided "FirePro_8.911.3.3_VistaWin7_X32X64_135673.exe" (found at [ATI FirePro™ Driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/fire/Pages/fire_win7-64.aspx)). Is there a way, to do that?

Thank you in advance for your support!

**Update:** I managed to accomplish a silent installation. I extracted the contents of the above mention installer-file and ran `\$_OUTDIR\Bin64\Setup.exe -Install`. (There are some other Parameters, just run `Setup.exe /?`). But i couldn't achieve to just install the drivers without the Cataclyst Control Center, and it seams the Control Center has some unfulfilled dependencies and so it crashes...

**Update 2:** Using `Setup.exe -Install -Use C:\Drivers\` i should be able to only install the drivers, but it seems that the Catalyst Control Center (CCC) will be installt too. The CCC keeps on crashing, but the driver is working. Now i just need to get rid of the CCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to install the required drivers using some sort of workaround, since I could not install the drivers using the provided setup.

I used the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&=tm&id=25175) to extract the drivers:

- Install the toolkit and run the Deployment Workbench
- Create a new Deployment Share (right click on `Deployment Shares` and select `New Deployment Shares`)
- In the createt Deployment Share right click on `Out-of-box Drivers` and select `Import Drivers` and select the location, where you saved the setup-files. (You may need to extract the files first)
- I then imported the Drivers from the Deployment Share (they're in a Folder called "Out-of-Box Drivers") to ICE, by just copying the files to the driver-location in the image.

I think there are smarter solutions, but at least that worked for me...